# Why can't I up-tick comments on a certain closed question?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, comments

[A question was migrated](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/458009/is-there-an-official-name-for-a-wooden-spiked-wall) from Writer.SE to our main site. There it was placed on hold for unclear. I agreed with a comment placed there from Lawrence (from our own community), but when I tried to up-tick it I received a message from the AI:

> This comment is not eligible for voting or flagging.

I have never seen this before, so I tried another question (also on hold) and there were no problems.

Anybody know what is going on here? Is it because it was migrated?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it's because it was migrated.  More specifically, the migration was rejected, which automatically locked the question.  This is done so that only one copy of the question is in play at any given time; the copy of the question on Writing was automatically unlocked when it was locked on EL&U.

The lock prevents you from upvoting comments, or really taking just about any action on the post, and that's why you get the error you do.  It could be a little more descriptive, perhaps something like this:

> You cannot upvote this comment because the post it's under is locked

But if you want that to happen, you'll probably have to post it as a separate feature request.  Most of the other actions you can take have more descriptive errors:

> This post has been locked; locked posts can't be voted on

But that one in particular is lacking.

Comment: Hmmnn...I thought it might be something like that. Yes, it could be more descriptive. Thanks for your quick response. Out of etiquette I will wait a bit before accepting this answer.